# Update control panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a problem with the update panel. I have made this table, and in that table i have two labels ("lblResult" and "lblCheat") which i need to be updated every time the button "btnCheck" or "ImageButton1" are clicked. 
When I click the next button, the whole table is updated, and it works just fine with the code i have.

I don't understand why aren't the labels updating since I am using the update panel the same way with the "btnNext" button and with the "btnCheck" and "ImageButton1"

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <center>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblSound" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Sentence: "></asp:Label></td>
                           <td colspan="2">
                               <center>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblSentence" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                               </center>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Audio: "></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td colspan="2">
                               <audio controls="">
       <source src="Sound/<%=FilePath %>" />
                               </audio>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="height: 11px">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Write the correct word: "></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td style="height: 11px">
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtWord" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtWord_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                           </td>
                           <td style="height: 11px">
                               <center>
                                   <asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" onclick="btnCheck_Click" 
                                       Text="Check" />
                                   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="30px" 
                                       ImageUrl="~/Besilka/Question-mark-icon.png" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                                       Width="30px" />
                               </center>
                           </td>
                       </tr>

                       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <center>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                               </center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <center>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblCheat" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                               </center>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       </ContentTemplate>
                       <Triggers>
                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCheck" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" EventName="Click" />
                       </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>

                   </table>
               </center>
               <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" onclick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next" />

           </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNext" EventName="Click" />
           </Triggers>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting your nested update panel UpdateMode="Conditional" . Also, just checking, do you have a ScriptManager on the page?

Comment: @Mausimo, UpdateMode="Conditional" and ChildrenAsTriggers="false" solved my problem.

Comment: I thought it would. Want me to create an answer, so that you can close out this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your nested update panel `UpdateMode="Conditional"`.

See this arcticle:

Specifically read **"How UpdatePanel Controls Are Refreshed"**, it actually talks about UpdateMode and nesting update panels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Update panels take a bit getting use to :)